# How to get AssociatedWorkItem from TFS Build via Rest API in C#?

Tags: c#, json, rest, tfs, azure-devops

I have some questions about the new tfs rest api :-)

first question: 
The new TFS Rest API interface is really nice, but how can I parse the JSON Object (e.g. /builds/ list) to a valid C# Object? Is there a Object in the Microsoft references, which I can use or do i have to string of Json?

second question:
I need the associated work items of the current TFS build (by Build ID?), it was easy to do it in the old TFS C# API. Is it possible for the new rest api as well?

Comment: Hello Waldemar. My answer helps u? Why the negative feedback in my answer? Can you remove them?

Comment: @JoãoMarcos Your answer was incorrect, which is why it received downvotes.

Comment: What part is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could install [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) for your project and in the package. The assemblies in this package has already help you transfer the json data to the corresponding object. Check this case: [What object returns from TFS2015 RestAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550941/what-object-returns-from-tfs2015-restapi)
2. Yes. You can get the associated work items of the current TFS build with REST API: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#work-items

The REST API is as below:

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/workitems?api-version={version}
```