# How to implement the await keyword?

Tags: api, asynchronous, tfs

I have written a code to get the projects from the TFS 2013 server using the tfs web api. As the methord is taking too long to execute i.e like 1.5 minutes, so i wanted to make this methord as async. So i added the async and task in the return type. When i see in visual studio is shows a message that the methord does not have await keyword. where should i add the await keyword. I am very new to async programming.

```
 public override async Task<List<Project>> GetProjects()
        {

        List<Project> retunResult = new List<Project>();

        using (var http = new HttpClient(GetHttpHandler()))
            {
            var response = http.GetAsync(_baseUrl + "_apis/projectCollections?" + tfsWebApiVersionSring).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                TFS2013TeamProjectCollection.Rootobject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TFS2013TeamProjectCollection.Rootobject>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                if (obj != null)
                    {
                    foreach (TFS2013TeamProjectCollection.Value projColl in obj.value)
                        {

                        if (projColl.state == "Started")
                            {
                            var responseProj = http.GetAsync(_baseUrl + projColl.name + "/_apis/projects?" + tfsWebApiVersionSring).Result;
                            if (responseProj.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                {
                                responseProj.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                                TFS2013TeamProject.Rootobject obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TFS2013TeamProject.Rootobject>(responseProj.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                                if (obj1 != null)
                                    {
                                    Project p;
                                    foreach (TFS2013TeamProject.Value TeamProj in obj1.value)
                                        {
                                        p = new Project();
                                        p.collectionName = TeamProj.collection.name;
                                        p.description = TeamProj.description;
                                        p.id = TeamProj.id;
                                        p.name = TeamProj.name;
                                        p.collectionName = TeamProj.collection.name;
                                        p.url = TeamProj.url;

                                        retunResult.Add(p);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    return retunResult;
                    }
                }
            }
        return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to this code snippet about using [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) to get something in async way.

```
public static async void RESTAPIMethod()
    {
        HttpClientHandler authtHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        };

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(authtHandler))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
                "Put the REST API URL here").Result)
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
        }
    }
```

**Another method about using TFS REST API:**

You could also install this [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) for your project. Then using these assemblies in this package to run a REST API with C#. This is different with the method above, it's much more convenient. Here is an example about get a build information using **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi** assembly in Async method. 
**Example**: 
[What object returns from TFS2015 RestAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550941/what-object-returns-from-tfs2015-restapi)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `Result` at all. Every place in your code where you have:

```
var resp = http.GetAsync(url).Result;
```

you should have:

```
var resp = await http.GetAsync(url);
```